# Auto-generate name for a custom TreeViewItem

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, design-time

I have a class derived from TreeviewItem(Custom TreeViewItem) which is used by a class derived from Treeview(custom Treeview Control).
When the user of my control adds items to my custom TreeView using the default design-time collection editor I want the newly added items to have a default name (like MyNode1, MyNode2 etc) and I want that to be written in XAML.
Any ideas on how to do that?
I noticed that when you drop a control from the toolbox it has a default name assigned to it. I would like to reuse this existing mechanism in Visual Studio 2010 if possible for my tree node classes.

Comment: This is surely not the answer you need, but seems to be hard. It might implies some sort of VS addin that writes the Name property for you. By the way ¿why do you need the name in every node?

Comment: In Blend, there's an option for "Automatically name interactive elements on creation", but I don't think Visual Studio has an equivalent option. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413373.aspx#ExpressionBlend)

Comment: Why? If you're treating nodes differently based on their name, then you should take the time to specify the Id or other identifier when you create the node.

Comment: Well , I am writing a custom control and I want my users to be able to access every node from code by name (like you can in windows forms). Furthermore I need to be able to import/export the tree's contents ... this is where it gets complicated because I need to export complex data in each node and the only reliable way to reimport that is if I have all the nodes named. An Id is fine too but that would have to be also part of the control's XAML footprint like the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeView`s and `TreeViewItem`s are user interface controls and should not be used to stored any kind of information that needs to be saved. Instead, you should create a hierarchical data type to store your information, bind that to the `TreeView.ItemsSource` property and provide a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to display the data as you wish.

This way, you can add new items to the `TreeView` by simply adding new data type objects to your bound collection in your view model or code behind. You can assign whatever values that you want to the objects before you add them to the collection and they will all be accessible from the collection at anmy time.

Comment: In a normal application that is true , the problem I am facing however is to write a custom control which looks like a treeView but has additional complex functionality. The functionality is relyant on other items in my framework. The goal is that the user of my control just draggs it on his page , sets someproperties and it should work. If he has to do something more advanced then he can write some code too but most of the times , just editing the control in XAML / using editors should be enough. He should not have to worry about complex details such as HDT's or datamodels behind.

Comment: Are you certain that you need to sub class the `TreeView`? You can do wonders with `Attached Properties`. See this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) if you're interested.

Comment: Well conceptually I do not need Attached properties as I am developing a new control (based on treeview) so I want to also keep the old one in it's default state